# MongoDB return both "before" and "after" document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

When I update a document in `MongoDB`, I can specify whether I want to return the original document or the newly-updated document. For example, using `PyMongo`, I can invoke:

```
user = db['users'].find_one_and_update(
    {'email': email},
    {'$set': {'last_login': time.time()}},
    return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER
)
```

I could also use [`ReturnDocument.BEFORE`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=find_one_and_update#pymongo.collection.ReturnDocument)

Is there a way for a *single* mongo query to return both the original and the new values?

Comment: You could avoid the second query to fetch the most recent.Return the BEFORE document and book keep the attributes being updated using variables . Use those variables to modify the BEFORE doc to get the AFTER doc. This however is viable solution only for single threaded application.

Comment: As stated, simply return the "BEFORE" modification state and then apply your "changes" to give you an "after". Even with something like `$inc` the document is effectively "locked for update" by the operation, so nothing other than your "update" can modify that "BEFORE" state.

Comment: @mintekhab There is no restriction on "single threaded" by how the `findAndModify` command inherent to the operation actually works. Nothing else can possibly modify the document so that the "AFTER" state would be different by the combination of the "BEFORE" and the modifications made within "that update".

Comment: @poundifdef, how about updating the question to use `$currentDate` in the update? I think that'd more clearly illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support from MongoDB to do what you are trying to do sadly...

> **returnNewDocument** | boolean | Optional. When true, returns the updated
>   document instead of the original document. Defaults to false.

in

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
   <filter>,
   <update document or aggregation pipeline>, // Changed in MongoDB 4.2
   {
     projection: <document>,
     sort: <document>,
     maxTimeMS: <number>,
     upsert: <boolean>,
     returnNewDocument: <boolean>,
     collation: <document>,
     arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
   }
)
```

From [`db.collection.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#definition)

---

You can use first `findOneAndUpdate()` with `returnNewDocument = false`, and get the old value, then do a regular `findOne()` but both in a transactional block, so even though there will be two calls to db, it will look like a single operation from outside.

With `PyMongo` it will be something like;

```
users = client.db.users
with client.start_session() as session:
    with session.start_transaction():
        oldUser = users.find_one_and_update(
            {'email': email},
            {'$set': {'last_login': time.time()}},
            session=session
        )
        newUser = users.find_one({'email': email}, session=session)
```

> return_document defaults to `ReturnDocument.BEFORE`, hence it is not explicitly set in `find_one_and_update()`

From [Transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/#transactions) and [`client_session(PyMongo)`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/client_session.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support of this feature. But if you really want to execute both commands on Database side and returns a single response - then you can write custom Javascript function (using [map_reduce](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=map_reduce#pymongo.collection.Collection.map_reduce), as [eval](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.eval) is deprecated) that will do that.

[By this link](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.1/examples/map_reduce.html) you can find few examples how to write custom Javascript functions using pymongo.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar kind of use case, I have taken the tack of writing "historical" revisions of a document into a separate database, and maintaining the key value of the record of reference in the primary.

This may or may not entail lots of back-end repercussions, but if not, it's a straightforward way of handling record versioning in a database that just wasn't designed for it.